# Wordpress Amazon affiliated api not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress, api

I have a Amazon affiliated API which is not working. I am using content egg on WordPress

I get an error:

[image]

```
Error: HTTP request status fails: 503 - Service Unavailable. Server replay: <?xml version="1.0"?> <ItemSearchErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/"><Error><Code>RequestThrottled</Code><Message>AWS Access Key ID: AKIAJDJICOD7PB7B646A. You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.</Message></Error><RequestID>9467ee2b-e508-48cc-8ff7-1fd17dbfe7fa</RequestID></ItemSearchErrorResponse>
```

What is originating the error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! I don't understand much of Amazon-ec2 but you might edit to add additional information: what were you doing before the error, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The error says everything you need to know:

You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.